# Можно ли динамически передавать компонент в <slot></slot>

Tags: javascript, vue.js

В структуре проекта есть каталог с компонентами, каждый хранит свой SVG код. Есть независимый компонент блока, в который через `props` приходят данные. Как динамически подключать нужный компонент с иконкой (должно быть 5 блоков, для каждого своя SVG (компонент vue))? Подумал про слоты, но ведь в них можно передать только контент или нет?

```
<template lang="pug">
  section.feautures
    .features__row
      info-block(v-for="i in 4")
        star-icon(slot="icon", fill="#876543", width="24px", height="24px")
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: `<component :is="componentName"></component>`
**Документация**: [динамическое переключение компонентов](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Иногда бывает полезно динамически переключаться между компонентами, например в интерфейсе с вкладками:

[image]

Показанное выше стало возможным с помощью элемента Vue `<component>` со специальным атрибутом `is`:

```
<!-- Компонент меняется при изменении currentTabComponent -->
<component :is="currentTabComponent"></component>
```

В примере выше `currentTabComponent` может содержать:

- имя зарегистрированного компонента, или
- объект с настройками компонента

Посмотрите [этот fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/o3nycadu/) чтобы поэкспериментировать с полным кодом, или [эту версию](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/b2qj69o1/) для примера привязки к объекту с настройками компонента вместо указания его имени.

Дополнительная информация доступна в разделе документации [Динамическим & Асинхронным компонентам](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html).

---

<sub>не придумал ничего лучше чем просто скопировать раздел документации...</sub>